# Redis in Docker (opened to Internet) suddenly started to try writing to /var/spool/cron , how to solve the issue?

Tags: docker, redis

I started using Redis 6.0 in docker container recently and faced with the following issue, suddenly: I see in logs that Redis container started to try writing to /var/spool/cron directory.

It is the second time I face the problem, first time It happened tonight (in several hours after launch). If I restart container, everything is fine again.

I have found link which stated that it happens so, because Redis container was hacked:
[The link](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/3594)

Is it true and how can I solve the issue?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM redis:6.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata

ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]

RUN chmod 0755 /usr/src/app/
RUN chmod 0755 /etc/crontabs/
RUN chmod 0755 /data/
```

Redis Config key points:

```
# bind 192.168.1.100 10.0.0.1
# bind 127.0.0.1 ::1

protected-mode no  # I thought that if I have user protected-mode works by default

port 6379

dbfilename dump.rdb

dir ./

user someusername allcommands allkeys on >somelongpassword
```

I run docker conatainer the following way:

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 -v myvol:/usr/src/app --name redis -d --network mynet redis
```

I attached print screen of my terminal window.

[image: Redis Container Error log]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never expose unprotected Redis to the Internet!

In your case, although you set ACL for *someusername*, you didn't disable the *default* user. And with *protected-mode* set to *no*, you expose your Redis instance to everyone.

You need to set *protected-mode* to *yes*. Also you can disable the *default* user with the following config:

```
user default off
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer explains why I was not able to turn ```protected-mode yes``` - due to existence of default user with no password. If the problem does not appear again next few days, I'll mark your excellent answer as solution.

Comment: Well, Redis works fine more than 48 hours now, so I really was cracked before. Thank you very much indeed !